# Proof of divergence/convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the series :
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{(n + 2)^3 n^\alpha  }}{{\sqrt[3]{{n^2  + 4n + 7\,}}\sqrt {n + 1} }}} $$
where $
\alpha  \in \Re $ . I managed to determine that when $
\alpha  \ge \frac{{ - 13}}{6}$ the series diverges, but what about the other cases ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

It behaves as (corrected due to @mvggz)
$$
\frac{n^{3+\alpha}}{n^{2/3+1/2}}=n^{\displaystyle\alpha+11/6}.
$$
If $\alpha+11/6<-1$, the series converges, in the other case diverges, from the quotient test.

Comment: That's false, it behaves as : $(3+\alpha) - (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{11}{6} + \alpha $

Comment: @mvggz $\alpha+11/6=11/6+\alpha$.

Comment: Yes @Przemysław Scherwentke, but $ \dfrac{3+\alpha}{2/3+1/2} $ is not equal to $(3+\alpha) - (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{11}{6} + \alpha$ as you say it in your answer, with the power of n. Thanks for the input about commutativity between two real numbers, I had forgot this one

Comment: @mvggz $n$ in the power!

Comment: No you should write either : $\frac{n^{3+\alpha}}{n^{\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}}} = n^{\frac{11}{6} + \alpha}$ or $ n^{(3+\alpha) - (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2})} = n^{\frac{11}{6} + \alpha}$ . None of them are what you wrote. Read your answer, instead of being unpleasant. The code proves that you write nonsense

Comment: This is exactly what you wrote :  n^{\dfrac{3+\alpha}{2/3+1/2}}=n^{\displaystyle\alpha+11/6} . You do mean to equal two powers that have nothing in common, and what's more the first comes out of nowhere since the general term is equivalent to : $\frac{n^{3+\alpha}}{n^{\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}}} = n^{\frac{11}{6} + \alpha}$

Comment: @mvggz Oh, you are right (and I am blind).  I am very sorry.

Comment: No it's ok, no need to apologize. But when I write a comment I want to help the one who wrote the answer if he has made a silly mistake (like everyone is capable of doing :) ). I saw your bounty on integration question by the way, thanks but you don't have to ;) . I just want to know, you think my answer is thorough enough?

Comment: @mvggz :-) I hope that I edited that answer without harm. (And our work on this question seems to be useless for OP).

Comment: It's perfect, and yes I have the feeling that you won't get any feedback on this :). I had forgot to upvote sry

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Divide denominator and numerator by $n^{(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2})}=n^\frac{7}{6}$